# Kotlin-idiomatic way to add an item to a list in a map

Tags: kotlin, collections, idioms

I have a `MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>` I'm adding items to, basically a collection where the same key is associated to several values.

Whenever I want to add a new value, I need to check first if there already is a list associated to the same key, initialize one if there isn't, and then add the value to the list.

I can do this in a pretty verbose way by doing

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map[key].add(value)
} else {
    map[key] = mutableListOf(value)
}
```

I also can do this in a very concise way by doing

```
map[key] = (map[key] ?: mutableListOf()) + mutableListOf(value)).toMutableList()
```

And in several other ways in between in terms of verbosity vs. conciseness.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin, though?

I'm not really aiming for conciseness but for a form that is immediately recognizable and understandable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [getOrPut](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html)

```
map.getOrPut(key) { mutableListOf() }.add(value)
```

Comment: this is by far the easiest and most idiomatic way of doing it. No reason to reinvent the wheel like the other answers.

Comment: or even more idiomatic `map.getOrPut(key) { mutableListOf() } += value`

Comment: Shortcut for people who landed here for something slightly different: maybe you want to replace `mutableListOf()` with `arrayListOf()` or `hashSetOf()` or some other `*Of()`

Answer (score 3):

I had to think of Python as it provides a `defaultdict` that can be used like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

data = [('red', 1), ('blue', 2), ('red', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1), ('blue', 5)]
d = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in data:
    d[k].add(v)

print(d.items()) # dict_items([('red', {1, 3}), ('blue', {2, 4, 5})])
```

Interestingly, Kotlin comes with something similar built-in, too, which is the [`withDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html) extension:

```
val data = listOf("red" to 1, "blue" to 2, "red" to 3, "blue" to 4, "red" to 1, "blue" to 5)
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Set<Int>>().withDefault { emptySet() }
for (d in data) {
    map[d.first] = (map.getValue(d.first) + d.second)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension function (name it so "that it is immediately recognizable and understandable"):

```kotlin
fun MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>.addValue(key: String, value: String) {
    if (containsKey(key)) {
        this[key]?.add(value)
    } else {
        this[key] = mutableListOf(value)
    }
}
```

Use the extension function wherever required:

```kotlin
map.addValue(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic version of the answer @Xid provided that will work regardless of the type of the key and value

```
fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, MutableList<V>>.addValue(key: K, value: V) {
    if (containsKey(key)) {
        this[key]?.add(value)
    } else {
        this[key] = mutableListOf(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers work but they're specific to using `MutableList` as value and are not concise enough for me, here's a solution exactly similar to python's `defaultdict`.

define this class (not a kotlin expert so improvements are welcome):

```
class defaultMutableMapOf<T, U>(
  private val map: MutableMap<T, U> = mutableMapOf(),
  private val defaultValue: () -> U,
) : MutableMap<T, U> by map {
  override fun get(key: T): U = if (key in map) {
      map[key]!!
  } else {
      map[key] = defaultValue.invoke()
      map[key]!!
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  val map1 = defaultMutableMapOf<String, Int> { 0 }

  map1["hello"]++
  map1["world"] += 2
  // map1 = {"hello":1,"world":2}

  val map2 = defaultMutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>> { mutableListOf() }

  map2["categories"].addAll(listOf("A", "B", "C"))
  map2["items"] += "item1"
  // map2 = {"categories":["A","B","C"],"items":["item1"]}
```

I don't know why Kotlin doesn't have something like this by default